# Redux and Typescript - PayloadAction and keyof

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

I am getting used to Typescript in Redux and have come across a problem with my reducer:

```
type Filter = {
  keyA: string;
  keyB: string;
  keyC: string;
};

export interface MyState {
  filter: Filter;
}

....
....

setFilter: (
  state,
  action: PayloadAction<{ key: keyof Filter; value: any }>
) => {
  if (state.filter[action.payload.key] !== action.payload.value) {
    state.filter = {
      ...state.filter,
      [action.payload.key]: action.payload.value,
    };
    .....
  }
},

    Parsing error: Unexpected token

  141 |     setFilter: (
  142 |       state,
> 143 |       action: PayloadAction<{ key: keyof Filter; value: any }>
      |                                          ^
  144 |     ) => {
```

My component dispatches a filter change, that updates the explicit filter, e.g.

```
dispatch(setFilter({"keyA": "newValue"}))
```

In the reducer, I just want to update the state to match the current filters.

It does not matter where I use the "keyof" (e.g. define a separate interface), it always throws an error like "unexpected token", "expected semicolon".

I would be very grateful if someone could help me.

Comment: Can you explain a little bit more, about your types like Filter, and what do you really want to do here?

Comment: I've updated the description

Comment: please provide reproducible example